# How to apply structs to modeling the data a view controller operates on

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, struct

I'm trying to embrace Swift's value types more in my application design, but I'm having some beginner difficulties. I know those generally don't go over well in the StackOverflow format for being opinion-based, but I think there are best-practices here that are probably not particularly subjective.

I understand all the theoretical benefits of structs, about avoiding shared mutable state, the copying behaviour that makes it easy to implement "undo", etc., but I have a hard time using it in practice for the model layer of my app (where I think structs would be most benefitial). I don't even know if this is a worthwhile pursuit, so bear with me.

Suppose I have a collection view, whose entries model pictures and their meta data. When a picture is selected, it would bring up a detail view that lets you view and edit the details of the picture and its associated meta data (filename, gps location, description, tags, ect.).

I'm struggling with how to design the interaction between my detail view controller, and my model layer which stores the repository of all of my images.

Here are some ideas I have about how I could design the interaction between the view and model layers.

1. The view controller could alias the model owned by the model layer. That is, the model layer will hold a collection of models objects. When one is selected, the VC will ask the model layer for one of the objects, which will be returned by reference. When the user changes details of the image, the VC's aliasing reference will be used to access the "active" model object, and update it directly.

   This sounds like the easiest approach, and is probably what I would do in other langauges (like Java), but it forces me to use a `class` to model my object, where otherwise a `struct` seems more appropriate. In this context, it appears (to me) that there's no need for identity. If two picture objects have the same fields, they're indistinguishable.
2. If I tried to keep my models as structs, my view controller could use a copy-modify-write pattern.

   - When an image is selected for editing, its model is copied into the VC.
   - The VC acts on its local copy, mutating it in-place
   - Eventually when the change needs to be persisted (such as when switching to a new image to edit, quiting the application, etc.) the VC overwrites the model layer's value with its local copy.

   This gets rids of any potential threading issues that might come with the shared mutable state in approach 1, but it comes with the downside of having the model become desyncronized from the VC, which could cause all kinds of consistency issues.
3. The next 3 approaches consider ideas that use a reactive framework like Combine or Rx.  I could use this pattern to subscribe my VC to receive updates to changes in the model layer and its `Picture` objects. However, I'm not sure how the "other way" would work; how the VC would inform the model to update. If I made the model subscribe itself to the view, then I think I would have an infinite loop, unless I added some mechanics around which changes should trigger observers and which shouldn't.

I'm not sure which is the best one, and I suspect this is one of those things that you pick up with experience (that I don't have yet :P). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not really reacting to the question of whether you should be using value of reference types, but a more general suggestion: the VC shouldn't mutate the _model_ at all. The VC should only handle the UI, the business logic (in your particular case, handling the actual editing of the model) should be handled by another entity (which exact entity depends on what architecture you use). If you let your view controller handle mutating your models and hence handle your UI and business logic by the same entity, you'll end up with the _Massive View Controller_ architecture. Separation of concerns.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Fair point, but that doesn't fully solve the problem. Suppose the VC didn't directly mutate the image objects (whether they be an instance of a class or struct), but asked a model layer object (`ImageRepository`, or whatever) to edit them on its behalf. How does the image repo know which image to edit in response to the VC's invocations of its methods?

Comment: As I've stated in the start of my comment, this wasn't really a question to your specific problem, but rather an unrelated general piece of advice. As for your second concern: if the VC has access to a collection of model objects, that collection must be indexed by some value (be it an `Array`, `Dictionary` or some other custom collection). The VC should pass the index of the selected image to the model layer, which then accessed the specified model and mutates it without directly exposing a mutable model to the VC.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Ahhh, yes, that was a variant that I had thought of before that I didn't list as one of my ideas. I dismissed that approach, because I didn't see any benefit. The key/index acts like an unnecessary layer of indirection, that didn't really decouple things at all. Calling APIs on a model repo was no different than calling them directly on the model object. Consider `self.imageRepo.set(location: loc, forImageNamed: someImageName)` vs `self.image.location = loc`.

Comment: The main benefit is the fact that with the first case, which you call an unneccessary layer of indirection, the model repo can do some validation, extra calculations, or anything else that needs doing before setting the value, while in the latter case, the VC can just directly set a property of the model without any validation taking place or any logic running before the setter (unless of course you create custom setters for the properties that need such validation/other logic being run before they are set)

Comment: @DávidPásztor The `image.location` could me migrated from being a stored property to a computed property, and insert any arbitrary validation and such. In fact, it's been a computed property all along. "unless of course you create custom setters" ah yes, precisely :)