# How to work with bindings when using a view model vs using @Binding in the view itself?

Tags: swift, swiftui

`@State` and `@Binding` work so well in `SwiftUI`, as long as you put all the view's data inside itself, like this:

```swift
struct ColorView: View {
    @Binding public var isBlue: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(isBlue ? .blue : .red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isBlue.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var isBlue: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ColorView(isBlue: $isBlue)
    }
}
```

It works without a problem and it's really simple. But `MVVM` says you should put all of the view's data inside a view model class, to separate UI from the model. But then you lose `@State` and `@Binding` completely. You lose this 2-way binding it seems. Sure, you can do it manually with `Combine` or something but that should not be the correct way, right?

Whenever I try anything, `SwiftUI` is really easy and convenient when you **don't** use view models. Once you put everything inside a view model class, though, everything breaks down and nothing works as convenient anymore. This can't be the case, they have to had thought of that. So I'm missing something here. I'd really appreciate any help. How would you code the above's example using view models (without "hacking" anything manually)? I tried but it doesn't even compile:

```swift
struct ColorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        // Binding or Published? Both doesn't seem to work
        @Binding var isBlue: Bool

        init(isBlue: Binding<Bool>) { // Or type Bool? But then we lose the binding
            self.$isBlue = isBlue
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isBlue ? .blue : .red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.isBlue.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isBlue: Bool = false // We would need a @State here, but then we lose @Published
    }

    var body: some View {
        ColorView(viewModel: .init(isBlue: /* ??? */)) // How to pass a binding here`
    }
}
```

Do I think of this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way (assuming that somewhere you call `TestView(viewModel: ViewModel())`):

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isBlue: Bool = false
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ColorView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
    }
}

struct ColorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isBlue ? .blue : .red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.isBlue.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this only works if the views share the view model. Doesn't this go against MVVM? Shouldn't every view have its own view model to decouple the components?

Comment: No it is not. They can but they not ought to. Reusability is still preferable =)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused. This way, `ColorView` can only ever be used in this context and nowhere else, right? This is actually the reason why I'm asking these questions because I've done it like this for years and now I've been trying to properly separate things to make them modular and reusable. And Apple says that @ObservableObject is for more complex data that cannot be properly handled with @State and @Binding, but @ObservableObject is something entirely different and you can't exactly reproduce @State and @Binding with pure SwiftUI while also keeping everything separated, it seems

Answer (score 2):

Using MVVM is your choice, apple officially does not recommend to use any design pattern. They have given us below concepts and it truly depends on us how we can use them.

1- Property wrappers(@State, @Binding, @Environment)

2- SwiftUI replacement of Storyboards

3- Combine framework provides a declarative Swift API for processing values over time like RxSwift, RxJava, RxKotlin etc.

> If you want to use MVVM you will still be using all of the above frameworks

**View**: Design and bind the view with SwiftUI.

**ViewModel**: Here you will use @Observable, @Published properties and bind it with View using SwiftUI binding concepts.

**Model**: Here we are using simple data models.

**Network**: Here we will be using Combine framework publisher/subscriber mechanism for handling network streams.

> NOTE:  You can combine all the above concepts and use it in another
>   design pattern like MVP, MVC or VIPER.

Comment: Sure, you're not forced to do MVVM. But it seems that `SwiftUI` was designed with it in mind. Many articles advice to use MVVM. But leaving that aside, it's still strange. Apple says that `@ObservableObject` is for situations in which @State and @Binding do not suffice or when you need more complex objects (like a view model). So I would think that `SwiftUI` was designed to let @ObservableObject do the same things you could do with @Binding. But it seemingly can't and that's what's confusing me. Why can't @ObservableObject do the cool things every beginner tutorial demonstrates with @Binding?

Comment: This is the single most pertinent criticism of SwiftUI + MVVM on the entire StackOverflow_and_the_whole_wide_Internet continuum. I know, because I read everything there is to read about it. At this moment I have 47 tabs open across 3 browser instances (and I closed some less relevant ones in the past few days).
So, Apple... what do you have to say in your defense...?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should share viewModel (as @Asperi mentioned)

But if you in situation like you've already coded 2 separated viewModels for both views and now you need to link them. Currently there is no nice way to do it, but there're always some ways to "hack it"

**1. Using Closure:**
Full Code base on your example will be like this (you can try on Preview)

```
struct ColorView: View {
    @Binding var isBlue: Bool
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(isBlue: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isBlue = isBlue
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(isBlue: isBlue))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isBlue ? .blue : .red)
            .onTapGesture { viewModel.isBlue.toggle() }
            .onChange(of: isBlue) { newValue in
                viewModel.isBlue = isBlue
            }
    }
    
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isBlue: Bool {
            willSet { updateIsBlue(newValue) }
        }
        var updateIsBlue: (Bool)->()
        
        init(isBlue: Binding<Bool>) {
            self.isBlue = isBlue.wrappedValue
            self.updateIsBlue = { isBlue.wrappedValue = $0 }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("is\(viewModel.isBlue ? "": " not") blue (using closure)") { viewModel.isBlue.toggle() }
            ColorView(isBlue: $viewModel.isBlue)
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isBlue = true
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

**2. Using NotificationCenter:**

```
let notifNameForIsBlue = Notification.Name("isblue")

struct ColorView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(isBlue: Bool) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(isBlue: isBlue))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isBlue ? .blue : .red)
            .onTapGesture { viewModel.isBlue.toggle() }
    }
    
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isBlue: Bool {
            willSet {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notifNameForIsBlue, object: newValue)
            }
        }
        
        init(isBlue: Bool) {
            self.isBlue = isBlue
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: notifNameForIsBlue)
                .compactMap { $0.object as? Bool }
                .assign(to: &$isBlue)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("is\(viewModel.isBlue ? "": " not") blue (using notification)") {
                viewModel.isBlue.toggle()
            }
            ColorView(isBlue: viewModel.isBlue)
        }
        
    }
    
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isBlue = true {
            willSet {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notifNameForIsBlue, object: newValue)
            }
        }
        
        init() {
            NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: notifNameForIsBlue)
                .compactMap { $0.object as? Bool }
                .assign(to: &$isBlue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is passing @Binding through your ViewModel like so

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var isBlue:Bool
    
    init(isBlue: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isBlue = isBlue
    }
}
```

I'm confused on what your example is trying to accomplish so I can't be sure this is what you're after but overall I think you want something like this:

```
struct ColorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(viewModel.isBlue ? .blue : .red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.isBlue.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State var color: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ColorView(viewModel: ViewModel(isBlue: $color)) // How to pass a binding here`
    }
}
```

You're now passing around that @Binding in your ViewModel, any changes made to it will be reflected wherever it is referenced.

Comment: Binding Is a DynamicProperty it only works in a View.

Comment: @loremipsum No this works fine, I use it in my ViewModel today as I posted, it compiles and works as expected.

Comment: `@Binding` is a `DynamicProperty` `propertyWrapper` it doesn't work anywhere but a `View`. Your code only "seems" to work because `ColorView(viewModel: ViewModel(isBlue: $color))` is recreating the object all the time.  put a `print` in the `init` for the object and see how many times it gets recreated.

Comment: >it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view. Instead, SwiftUI provides the StateObject property wrapper, which creates a single source of truth for a reference type that you store in a view hierarchy. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app

Comment: Good article but the take away from the "unsafe to create..." isn't "Don't use @Binding (or a DynamicProperty) outside a view" its "Don't instantiate an @ObservableObject in a view, you should pass it in" which is what I'm doing here (though I am initing it in an _upstream_ view).  See the `struct BookView: View` example in the article you linked.

Comment: `Binding` is a property wrapper, and property wrappers work on all property declarations. It is valid (although unusual) to use `@Binding` inside an `ObservableObject`; it ends up being syntactic sugar for declaring a `Binding<Bool>` and accessing its `.wrappedValue` property.

_Altering_ the binding *might* cause changes to SwiftUI; that depends entirely on how it's used in other places.

Comment: I see, so you're saying: Sure you can technically use `@Binding` but if its not a View you should just use `Binding<Type>` directly because `@Binding` is doing some extra work for you that you don't need in that situation

Comment: I created a small test that shows that `Binding` does in fact work outside of a SwiftUI View. It also gives insights why you wouldn't want to do that: https://gist.github.com/helje5/fdc7e43e32aab58ad0e799dafeabf151

Generally if a PW conforms to DynamicProperty, it does have functionality related to the `update` call of that, which provides context within SwiftUI.
That doesn't mean it can't possibly work outside of a View, like Binding, but it is a strong indication that you shouldn't.

Comment: So then is the right path to use Binding<> instead of @Binding `var isBlue: Binding<Bool>` on the ViewModel and then read/write the value in the view as `viewModel.isBlue.wrappedValue = true/false` etc?

Comment: Lol, if you have other properties in that observable object they will get reset all the time, there is no lifecycle management.

Comment: but do whatever you feel is right if recreating the object for no good reason whenever SwiftUI decides is ok with you go ahead. Binding only belongs in a View.

Comment: What syntax you use to declare the binding doesn't matter, you can either do `@Binding` or `Binding`, they are essentially the same w/ different syntax.

Comment: @hnh Binding as a literal wont reload the body only the property wrapper will. If you connect it with a proper source of truth the source of truth might reload but Binding literal won’t.

Comment: What is a "Binding as a literal"? Property wrappers are just syntactic sugar. (what makes the structure update and behave in SwiftUI is the `DynamicProperty` conformance)

Comment: Binding<Bool> I call a literal, @hnh

Comment: I call that a type. Those are and behave the same wrt to updates: `@Binding var i : Int` and `var i : Binding<Int>`.

Comment: @hnh put an actual View in your test. I am not saying it doesn’t connect and the underlying value or doesn’t get updated I am saying the View wont get reloaded. Don’t use any other wrappers just with the code you have plus a body that displays/updates.

Comment: It does. The test was for showing the opposite. PWs are resolved at compile time, SwiftUI doesn't seen anything of them at runtime (they are exactly the same).
As mentioned the key thing is DynamicProperty. The update on those is what makes SwiftUI tick.
But hey, try for yourself :-)

Comment: Here is a small toy for understanding dynprops, you are welcome: https://gist.github.com/helje5/ea524d430dec7fad024033c0b7aa27b0

Comment: @hnh remove `wrapper` and try and edit  `noWrapper` from the body with a Stepper or something see if it works. Binding is a two way connection. Just as is don't add more wrappers.