# How to rewrite `@Binding` to ViewModel

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to make a `ViewModel` for only `CustomTextField` below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      CustomTextField(text: $text)
      Text(text)
    }
  }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
  @Binding var text: String

  var body: some View {
    TextField("title", text: $text)
  }
}
```

I tried to rewrite it as follows, but I couldn't figure out how to rewrite it properly.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      CustomTextField(text: $text)
      Text(text)
    }
  }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = CustomTextFieldViewModel()

//  @Binding var text: String <-- How to replace ViewModel

  var body: some View {
    TextField("title", text: $text)
  }
}

final class CustomTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
  private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

  @Published var text = ""
}
```

If I not use `@Binding`, I will not be able to notification with the parents view.
This `CustomTextField` is modular and I want it to be able to be used by any parent,
but I don't know how to write it to mimic `@Binding` using a ViewModel.(In other words, I want to link `ContentView's text` to `ViewModel's text` somehow.)

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm doing this?

Or

Is it possible to solve the problem by using another `Property Wrappers` that is not `@Published`?

Or

Is there a way to initialize the ViewModel that solves this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want a `@State` in the parent View (`ContentView`) and a `ViewModel` in the Child View (`CustomTextField`). So you have to declare the `@Binding` in your ViewModel :

```
final class CustomTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var text: String
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: CustomTextFieldViewModel
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        viewModel = CustomTextFieldViewModel(text: text)
    }

  var body: some View {
    TextField("title", text: $viewModel.text)
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      CustomTextField(text: $text)
      Text(text)
    }
  }
}
```

**But**, you shouldn't use this solution. `@Binding` and `@State` are only made to be used in `View`s.

You could use a single ViewModel, instantiated in the parent view, and shared by the two Views (like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946945/16125496) - *edit*: or in the @workingdog's answer ).

Or, if you want to use two different ViewModels (one to manage the `ContentView` and one other for the `CustomTextField`) you can use Combine :

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var vm = ContentViewViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CustomTextField(viewModel: vm.customTextFieldVM)
        TextField("", text: $vm.text)
        Text(vm.text)
    }
  }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CustomTextFieldViewModel

  var body: some View {
      TextField("title", text: $viewModel.text)
  }
}


final class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String {
        didSet {
            if text != self.customTextFieldVM.text {
                self.customTextFieldVM.text = text
            }
        }
    }
    var customTextFieldVM: CustomTextFieldViewModel
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    init() {
        text = ""
        customTextFieldVM = CustomTextFieldViewModel()
        customTextFieldVM.$text
            .sink {
                if $0 != self.text {
                    self.text = $0
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
final class CustomTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String
    init() {
        text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to understand my intentions, but when I actually try to do it, it seems that with your code, the value I entered disappears from the TextField after typing a few characters.

Comment: @Shingo : If I copy-paste the code I wrote in Xcode, I have no problem. I updated my answer with an other approach.

Comment: I see. The old code is still not working in my environment, but the new code works. I'll read the code.

Comment: @Shingo : mine was Xcode 13 beta ; change the `@StateObject` by an `@ObservedObject`. I tested on Xcode 12.4, it works.
I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: `two different ViewModels` looks good. but It looks like `sink` needs `weak self`.

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi : Indeed, `sink` requires a` weak` self. If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references. And upvote the answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

to use CustomTextFieldViewModel in CustomTextField
you have to declare CustomTextFieldViewModel in the parent, otherwise the "text" data in CustomTextField will not update the parent view.
Try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = CustomTextFieldViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: viewModel)
            Text(viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CustomTextFieldViewModel

    var body: some View {
        TextField("title", text: $viewModel.text)
    }
}

final class CustomTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    @Published var text = ""
}
```

If you want to use only the text part, try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = CustomTextFieldViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(text: $viewModel.text)
            Text(viewModel.text)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("title", text: $text)
    }
}
```